# How can I stack buttons rather than queue them in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, frames

At the moment I have 3 basic buttons being displayed:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)
leftFrame = Frame(root)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
botFrame = Frame(root)
botFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(leftFrame, text="Button 1", fg="Black")
button2 = Button(leftFrame, text="Button 2", fg="Black")
button3 = Button(leftFrame, text="Button 3", fg="Black")

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

The 3 buttons at the moment will stick to the left frame on the window, however then will queue next to each other rather than stack one on top of the other, how do i fix this?

Comment: You're telling them to be on the left. Have you tried telling them to be on top (`side=TOP`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly telling them to be side-by-side with `side=LEFT`. You want `side=TOP` so that they are placed at the top of the empty space in the frame.

```
button1.pack(side=TOP)
button2.pack(side=TOP)
button3.pack(side=TOP)
```

When you use pack, the values TOP, LEFT, RIGHT and BOTTOM tell the widget which side of the *remaining* space they should occupy. The first time you use LEFT it will reserve the left side of the whole frame for the widget. The next time you use LEFT, that refers to the space remaining in the widget *excluding* the left edge since that already has a widget in it. The net effect is that LEFT causes widgets to be arranged left-to-right, RIGHT arranges them right-to-left, and so on.

Comment: I have the same problem as the author of this post, but I want to pack both buttons on the frame's left (NOT MIDDLE). How can I do this? I can't use `grid` or `place`.

Answer (score 3):

Explore the [`grid`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm) function. Change your `pack` statements to

```
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
button2.grid(row=1,column=0)
button3.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

Comment: why column 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @BryanOakley Used to do column 0 from when I was young, perhaps due to bad programming practice, Will edit if you think I should. Is it bad to have `column = 1`?

Comment: It's not bad per se, it's just odd since the first column is column 0. Using 1 without good reason makes the code confusing.

Comment: @BhargavRao Using `column=1` can only be useful if you think you will grid (in the future)  something in column 0.