# Tkinter buttons not stacking on left

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to stack two buttons on the frame's left (NOT MIDDLE).

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button, LEFT

def pressed():
    print("Button Pressed!")


root = tk.Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text="Button1", command=pressed)
button1.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20)

button2 = Button(frame, text="Button2", command=pressed)
button2.pack(side=LEFT, ipadx=20)


root.mainloop()
```

I have also tried:

```
button1.pack(side=LEFT, fill='x' pady=20)
```

but it does not change anything in output.

Required output:

```
  +------------------------------+
  |    |(20px)                   |
  |[Button1] <------------------ |
  |    |(20px)                   |
  |[-(20px)-Button2-(20px)-] <-- |
  |                              |
  |                              |
  +------------------------------+
```

Everything else is fine in code, I just want both buttons to be stacked in the LEFT of the frame.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173094/how-can-i-stack-buttons-rather-than-queue-them-in-tkinter) solution but it's placing buttons in the middle.

***Note***: I can not use `grid` or `place`.

Comment: Since you used `side=LEFT` for both buttons, then they will be put side by side horizontally.  You need to use `side=TOP` and `anchor=W` to put them side by side vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame only packs, without any `expand` or `fill` parameter so your buttons are going to stay in the top center because the frame will only expand enough to fit the buttons and no more.  So in order for the buttons to appear on the left you would need something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button, LEFT

def pressed():
    print("Button Pressed!")


root = tk.Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH) #control the frame behavior

button1 = Button(frame, text="Button1", command=pressed)
button1.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W, pady=20)# pack top and left

button2 = Button(frame, text="Button2", command=pressed)
button2.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

Or a less desireable way, set the frame size and prevent it from propagating like so.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button, LEFT

def pressed():
    print("Button Pressed!")


root = tk.Tk()

frame = Frame(root, height=1000, width=1000)
frame.pack()
frame.pack_propagate(0) #stops the frame from shrinking to fit widgets

button1 = Button(frame, text="Button1", command=pressed)
button1.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W, pady=20)

button2 = Button(frame, text="Button2", command=pressed)
button2.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first solution worked without adding `expand` and `fill`. Thanks.